For every $d\in\mathbb{N}$ and $s\in [0,d]$ there exists an $s$-set $A\subset\mathbb{R}^d$
I would like to prove that for every $d\in\mathbb{N}$ and $s\in [0,d]$ there exists an $s$-set $A\subset\mathbb{R}^d$, where $s$-set means that $0<\mathcal{H}^s(A)<\infty$.
For $s=0$, you just take any finite subset of $\mathbb{R}^d$, and for $s=d$, any compact set with non-zero volume (Lebesgue measure) suffices, e.g. the unit ball. I also know that for $0<s<d$, you can achieve any Hausdorff measure using a construction similar to the Cantor set. I've been trying but couldn't figure out how to make it work. Any hint is appreciated!

There is a theorem, which states the following:
Let $K$ be compact and $f_1, \ldots, f_n$ be similarities with quotients $q_1, \ldots, q_n<1$ and dimension $s$. If for $i\neq j$ we have $f_i(K)\bigcap f_j(K)=\emptyset$, then $K$ is an $s$-set.
If you are not familiar with this theorem, you can try proving this using Hölder-functions.
From the theorem, one can construct an $s$-dimensional Cantor-like set. Take the $d$-dimensional unit cube, and have $n=2^d$ similarities: for each vertex $i$ of the cube, let the similarity $f_i$ scale the unit cube from vertex $i$ with fiexd quotient $q=q_i\leq \frac{1}{2}$. These similarities indeed satisfy the conditions of the theorem and gives a Cantor-like fixed-set $K$. For the dimension, this gives the equation: $1=2^d\cdot q^s$ concluding $s=-\log_{q}(2^d)$. (Note that as $q<1$, this is indeed positive.) From the theorem, we immediately have that this $K$ is indeed an $s$-set. Choosing $q$ from $\left(0, \frac{1}{2}\right]$ gives all the desired $s$-sets (by continuity and looking at $q=0^+$ and $q=\frac{1}{2}$).
